# Python: Regex to find but not include an alphanumeric

Tags: python, regex

Is there an regular expression to find, for example, `">ab"` but do not include `">"` in the result?

I want to replace some strings using `re.sub`, and I want to find strings starting with `">"` without remove the `">"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a back reference in sub:

```
import re
test = """
>word
>word2
don't replace
"""
print re.sub('(>).*', r'\1replace!', test)
```

Outputs:

```
>replace!
>replace!
don't replace
```

I believe this accomplishes what you actually want when you say "I want to replace some strings using `re.sub`, and I want to find strings starting with '`>`' without remove the '`>`'."

Comment: yes, the * (many or none) is what I had forget about.. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You want a positive lookbehind assertion. See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

```
r'(?<=>)ab'
```

It needs to be a fixed length expression, it can't be a variable number of characters. Basically, do

```
r'(?<=stringiwanttobebeforethematch)stringiwanttomatch'
```

So, an example:

```
import re

# replace 'ab' with 'e' if it has '>' before it

#here we've got '>ab' so we'll get '>ecd'
print re.sub(r'(?<=>)ab', 'e', '>abcd') 

#here we've got 'ab' but no '>' so we'll get 'abcd'
print re.sub(r'(?<=>)ab', 'e', 'abcd')
```

Comment: I think I don't understand. When I type `r'(?<=>asdf)sd'` I get `'(?<=>asdf)>a'`. Could you post an example of this solution?

Comment: +1 `(?<=...)` is very ugly and not intuitive, but it works very good =) Thanks for showing this alternative.

Comment: Ow, I got it, its an arrow to the left.. (I was in slow brain mode)

Comment: Check out the docs, the negative forms are pretty useful too (match if not preceeded by / not followed by)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to avoid using the re module you can also use the [startswith()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) string method.

```
>>> foo = [ '>12', '>54', '34' ]
>>> for line in foo:
...     if line.startswith('>'):
...             line = line.strip('>')
...     print line
... 
12
54
34
>>>
```

Comment: He wants to `find strings starting with ">" without remove the ">"`. Your version removes the `>`